# Unexpected Python interpreter output

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-handling

I wrote an extremely basic python code which creates a file and appends 10 lines in it

```
>>> b = open("b.txt", 'w')
>>> for i in range(10):
...     b.write("line %d\n" %i)
... 
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
```

Why are 7's outputted on the screen?

Comment: No of bytes it has written.

Comment: Try this at the command prompt: `for x in range(10): x**2`; then extrapolate :)

Comment: From `help(b.write)`: "Returns the number of characters written".

Answer (score 0):

The '7's outputted to the console are the number of bytes written to the file, and are returned by the file.write function. See the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/io.html#io.RawIOBase.write).

In addition, you should generally use the following format to handle files:

```
with open("b.txt", "w") as f:
    for i in range(10):
        f.write("line %d\n" %i)
```

This avoids having to manually close the file after you've finished with it.

Comment: This should be a comment, as it doesn't address anything the OP is asking about.

Comment: This would better serve as a comment than as an answer. While the point made is valid, it is totally irrelevant to the question asked.

Answer (score 0):

This comes from the behavior of the interactive interpreter. You'll notice a similar effect if you write

```py
>>> x = 5
>>> x
5
```

When you have a statement and don't set it equal to anything, the interactive interpreter will `repr` the output/return value and display it in the terminal. The return value for a file write command is the number of bytes written to the file.